# How to add get image from JSON file, add class and append in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am trying to add a class on image, that i am taking from local JSON  file. 
my JSON file:

```
[{
    "posterPath" : "<img src = imgsMovie/MovieName/poster.jpg>"

}]
```

This is my file i am taking from JSON, it is an image tag.
Now,
I want in this image to have an class dynamically added with jQuery.

my div is

```
<div class='rightposter'></div>
```

And this is how i get my image from JSON

```
$(".rightposter").append(data[i].posterPath)//this will display my image on my page without class.
```

How can i add class inside img tag?

Comment: Yeah your JSON is invalid.

Comment: `$(".rightposter").append($(data[i].poasterPath).addClass("myNewClass"));` - Basically turn the JSON string of the image tag, in to an image node a bit earlier, then use jQuery to append the class :)

Comment: I have to ask - did you mean "posterPath" instead of "poasterPath" ? (especially since your class is "rightposter")

Comment: Yes, i typo sry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a cleaner way to insert dynamically constructed HTML tags using jQuery.

Use the following syntax to build your HTML and to append it to the DOM:

```
$div = $('.rightposter');

$('<img />', {
 'src': data[i].posterPath,
 'class': "myClass" //put your class name here
}).appendTo($div);
```

And change your JSON data structure to the following:

```
[{
    "posterPath" : "imgsMovie/MovieName/poster.jpg"

}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".rightposter").append(data[i].poasterPath)
```

change to

```
$(".rightposter").append($(data[i].poasterPath).addClass("your class"));
```

```js
    $(".rightposter").append($("<img src=http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-130-67-5.jpg>").addClass("red"));
```

```css
.red { border:3px solid red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='rightposter'></div>
```

Comment: This is adding the class in the div element , not in the img  element

Answer (score 1):

if this is the only img tag in code then you can write $('img').addClass('your class') or $('.rightposter img').addClass('your class');

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to get image and add class on it.

```
$(".rightposter").append(data[i].posterPath).find("img").addClass("myClass");
```

Comment: But not very efficiently

Comment: @mplungjan Any suggestion to improve it will be appreciated.

Comment: @mplungjan yes I saw that but OP wants class on image itself, not on container.

Comment: See the example. It's on the image

Comment: Find is not very efficiently